# Reading barcode from webcam in PHP web application

Tags: php, javascript, flash, webcam, barcode

Want to add following feature to my web application: To decode barcodes generated by [this script](http://www.ashberg.de/php-barcode/download/#php-barcode) .  with webcam and use values in PHP web application.

Is that possible? if yes how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not with PHP, seeing as it is server side. But, you could accomplish this with java, javascript, or some other client side languages.

javascript (jQuery) webcam plugin

http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-webcam-plugin/

EDIT -- how this would be done is to take the picture with javascript, and then send it back to the server to decode by PHP.

http://www.inliteresearch.com/homepage/support/kb_programming.html

Answer (score 3):

I happened to come across a project where someone actually accomplished this in a pretty nice way using Javascript:

https://serratus.github.io/quaggaJS/

It only handles a few types of barcodes, but it may be a good starting point if you need the others. You can most likely have Javascript post these back to PHP using AJAX or have them update a form field to be submitted.